# forgotten laundry stinks - electronic solution

Tags: amplifier, sound, piezo-buzzer

I forget to move the laundry from the washer to the dryer. The clothes stink when left over night (this has occurred many times before).

The buzzer is short and weak therefore, I would like to add a continuous loud buzzer to mix. This will wake up even the heaviest sleeper...

I would like it to alarm when it receives a electronic signal (I will connect this to the washer buzzer) it will buzz until switched off.  A simple on/off switch or button will do.

I guess it would be really cool to shut it off when the door opens or a weight sensor detects the laundry has actually been moved. This is really optional.

Ideas?

Comment: without knowing what kind of power is running through the buzzer it would be very hard to suggest a completed circuit for your task, but there will be ~3 parts, a trigger, a buzzer/driver, and reset/timer ... maybe breaking that up would allow you to ask better questions.

Comment: Have you opened up washer to figure out where the buzzer and sensors are?  What have you found out?  What have you tried?  It is hard to help you if you have no done any research.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the best solutions are the easiest.  This is one of those cases.

Buy a standard timer from the local department store.  Usually in the kitchen gadget isle.  Or use your smartphone.  Just set the timer for some appropriate amount of time.  Done!  If it is still not loud enough, then carry the timer with you as you move around the house.

If you really want an EE solution then get a simple 8-bit MCU, some sort of power, a loud buzzer, and hook it all up.  It doesn't need to be complex.  Maybe just a fixed "buzzer will go off 2 hours after power is applied", sort of thing.  Beyond that, I don't know what sort of answer you are looking for.  But I guarantee that you'll be spending more for this than just getting a simple timer at the store.

On a non-engineering note:  to help prevent that smell, you need to keep mold from growing.  Start by periodically cleaning out your washing machine.  Do this by either running a load of whites with bleach, or using the "sanitize" cycle on your washer.  Then, between washes when your machine is idle, keep the door/lid open to allow the insides to dry out (and thus prevent mold from growing).  You will still need to move the clean clothes to the dryer quickly, just not as quickly.